# Rectangle fitting some text and scaled circuit from circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, fit

I am trying to draw a rectangle with some text on the left and with an electrical schema on the right (all inside one rectangle)
I am using following packages:

```
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes}
```

The scheme I want to place into the rectangle is something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} [ european resistors ]
\draw[help lines, dotted] (-5,-5) grid (10,6); 


% \scalebox{0.6}{
\draw (4, 2) 
to [vR, *-*]  ++(-2,-2)
to node (l1) {} ++(0,0)
to [vR, *-*] ++(2,-2)
to [short, -o] ++(0, -1)
to node (b1) {} ++(0,0)
to [short] ++(0, 1)
to [vR, *-*]  ++(2,2)
to node (r1) {} ++(0,0)
to [vR, *-*]    ++(-2,2)
to [short,-o]   +(0, 1)
to node (t1) {} ++(0,0)
; 
% }
\node[fit=(t1) (b1) (l1) (r1), draw, black, rectangle, inner sep=10pt]{};


\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I try to scale it with some factor (0.6) it accidentally scales nodes, but doesn't do the same with the outer rectangle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} [ european resistors ]
\draw[help lines, dotted] (-5,-5) grid (10,6); 


\scalebox{0.6}{
\draw (4, 2) 
to [vR, *-*]  ++(-2,-2)
to node (l1) {} ++(0,0)
to [vR, *-*] ++(2,-2)
to [short, -o] ++(0, -1)
to node (b1) {} ++(0,0)
to [short] ++(0, 1)
to [vR, *-*]  ++(2,2)
to node (r1) {} ++(0,0)
to [vR, *-*]    ++(-2,2)
to [short,-o]   +(0, 1)
to node (t1) {} ++(0,0)
; 
}
\node[fit=(t1) (b1) (l1) (r1), draw, black, rectangle, inner sep=10pt]{};

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I really have no idea how to put text inside this pseudo-fitting  rectangle.

I am relatively new to the world of `tikz`, so please give me advice on how to accomplish my task: to place text with scaled scheme inside?

To compound the problem, I need to draw several boxes (with text and scaled schemas) like the above. So, I will be very disappointed if there is not some convenient method of grouping blocks of nodes (and connections between them) as a single node, and then being able to use it further (as a sort of a variable) in other connections.

Comment: Could you also point me to the service where it is possible to get a  link to a compiled latex code for in turn pasting it here ?

Comment: I use http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/ but it does not support all packages, in particular it does not support circuitikz

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always create complete, compilable examples, rather than (a collection of) snippets. Makes it easier for us, and we don't have to make any assumptions about how you've done things. You can compile the PDF on your own machine, take a screenshot, and upload that to your post.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out the possibility of screenshot uploading. I have tried once to add image before, but see only form with url to image (web-based) and no possibility  to add file from localhost. Edited with compiled results and full examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code below  does what you're after. Note first that I've removed the `\scalebox`, and instead I've added `transform shape,scale=0.6` as options to the `\draw` creating the circuit. The first of those is needed because the components are created as `node`s, and these are not affected by `scale` unless you add `transform shape`. 
If you don't want the components to be scaled, just the distances between them, remove `transform shape`.

I also modified the circuit-drawing a little, there is no need for the `++(0,0)` stuff, and for this case `coordinate`s work fine, you don't need `node`s with the empty label.

Finally I included the new `sometext` node, which is placed to the left of the `l1` node, in the `fit`ted node.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} [ european resistors ]
%\draw[help lines, dotted] (-5,-5) grid (10,6); 

\draw [transform shape,scale=0.6] (4, 2) 
to [vR, *-*]  ++(-2,-2)
coordinate (l1) 
to [vR, *-*] ++(2,-2)
to [short, -o] ++(0, -1)
coordinate (b1) 
to [short] ++(0, 1)
to [vR, *-*]  ++(2,2)
coordinate (r1) 
to [vR, *-*]    ++(-2,2)
to [short,-o]   +(0, 1)
coordinate (t1) 
; 

\node (sometext) [left=of l1,align=left,text width=4cm] 
  {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur and a bunch more text just for this example.};

\node[fit=(t1) (b1) (sometext) (r1), draw, black, rectangle, inner sep=10pt]{};

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I had more upvotes , I would give them all to you! Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know, by the way, why i couldn't use one plus (`to [vR, *-*]    +(-2,2)`) in `circuitikz` environment, as i can do in tikz - to draw line, but do not move drawing pointer to the end of line?

Comment: Unless I misremember, the ``to`` operation in TikZ simply  doesn't support ``+()`` or ``++()``.

Comment: And what is possible to use instead of `to` ?  maybe `--` ?

Comment: @PavelShvechikov (You haven't actually used any upvotes yet.) The `+()` operation doesn't seem to work with `to` as @kenshin says. Try for example `\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)node{S} to[bend right] +(1,0) to[bend left] +(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: I cannot use up vote button unless i have reputation more than 15. (

Comment: @PavelShvechikov Oops, sorry, I had forgotten about that limitation.